# I am not able to load plugins in Angular Js file. How to load it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

In the below code, I have used stateProvider to retrieve the page and load the respective plugins which are mentioned in the source code:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            views: {
                '': {templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard/dashboard.html'},
                'topnavbar@dashboard': { templateUrl: 'partials/common/topnavbar.html' },
                'navigation@dashboard': { templateUrl: 'partials/common/navigation.html' },
                'footer@dashboard': { templateUrl: 'partials/common/footer.html' },
                'content@dashboard': {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard/dashboard-content.html',
                    controller: 'DashboardCtrl as dashboard',
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                        {
                            name: 'angles',
                            files: ['js/libs/plugins/chartJs/angles.js', 'js/libs/plugins/chartJs/Chart.min.js']
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'angular-peity',
                            files: ['js/libs/plugins/peity/jquery.peity.min.js', 'js/libs/plugins/peity/angular-peity.js']
                        },
                        {
                            serie: true,
                            name: 'angular-flot',
                            files: [ 'js/libs/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js', 'js/libs/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.time.js', 'js/libs/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js', 'js/libs/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.spline.js', 'js/libs/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js', 'js/libs/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js', 'js/libs/plugins/flot/curvedLines.js', 'js/libs/plugins/flot/angular-flot.js', ]
                        }
                    ]);
                }
            }
        })
}
```

Please see if I am doing any mistake in resolve property ?

Answer (score 1):

There is not property `name` for [ocLazyLoad#load](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/oclazyload-service).

You have to first [predefine the configuration of your modules](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/oclazyloadprovider) specifying  name and files:

```
$ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
    modules: [{
        name: 'angles',
        files: ['js/libs/plugins/chartJs/angles.js', 'js/libs/plugins/chartJs/Chart.min.js']
    }, {
        name: 'angular-peity',
        files: ['js/libs/plugins/peity/jquery.peity.min.js', 'js/libs/plugins/peity/angular-peity.js']
    }, {
        serie: true,
        name: 'angular-flot',
        files: ['js/libs/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js', 'js/libs/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.time.js', 'js/libs/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js', 'js/libs/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.spline.js', 'js/libs/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js', 'js/libs/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js', 'js/libs/plugins/flot/curvedLines.js', 'js/libs/plugins/flot/angular-flot.js']
    }]
});
```

Then you can load the predefined configuration:

```
$ocLazyLoad.load(['angles', 'angular-peity', 'angular-flot']);
```

Finally your code:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard/dashboard.html'
            },
            'topnavbar@dashboard': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/common/topnavbar.html'
            },
            'navigation@dashboard': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/common/navigation.html'
            },
            'footer@dashboard': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/common/footer.html'
            },
            'content@dashboard': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard/dashboard-content.html',
                controller: 'DashboardCtrl as dashboard',
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            loadPlugin: function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load(['angles', 'angular-peity', 'angular-flot']);
            }
        }
    });
```